# WKWebView didFinishNavigation is not working with frame/iframes

Tags: ios, webkit, wkwebview, scorm

I am trying to load a html which has 2 frames in it using WKWebView. I am getting all the navigation delegates for main frame once but not getting didCommit and didFinish callback for subframes.

My sample html is like this:

```
https://example.com <html><head><base href="https://example.com"></head><frameset framespacing="0" rows="*,0" frameborder="0" noresize><frame name="sco" src="https://example.com//assets/s/uruq3acajh9u/x/mobile/path/loading.html"><frame name="adaptor" src="https://example.com//assets/s/uruq3acajh9u/content/mobile/path/1.html?sco_url=https://example.com/content/elearningngx/VHDRczdEy5kO_pRfKsNJEA/1571433806/0088Z2lPcUR4MVljWWlPUVYvSjNrby9OVjJzbk84OENkN1h3SVl3UVBPMG9sb3lXNFFsaHUwT2xDbVhFTzVpMWdiNQ==RnJpIE9jdCAxOCAxMzoyMzoyNiBVVEMgMjAxOQ==/eot/index.html"></frameset></html>

func setupWebView(){  
        if (self.webView != nil){  
            self.webView.removeFromSuperview()  
        }  

        HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookieAcceptPolicy = .always  

        let userContentController = WKUserContentController()  
        userContentController.addUserScript(HTMLViewScripts.viewportScript)  


        let pref = WKPreferences()  
        pref.javaScriptEnabled = true  
        pref.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true  
        pref.setValue(true, forKey: "allowFileAccessFromFileURLs")  
        pref.setValue(true, forKey: "_allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs")  

        let wkWebConfig = WKWebViewConfiguration()  
        wkWebConfig.preferences = pref  
        wkWebConfig.userContentController = userContentController  

        let wkWebSiteStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.nonPersistent()  
        wkWebConfig.websiteDataStore = wkWebSiteStore  

        self.webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: Constants.screenSize.width, height: self.playerContainer.frame.size.height), configuration: wkWebConfig)  
        self.webView.navigationDelegate = self  
        self.webView.uiDelegate = self  
        self.playerContainer.addSubview(self.webView)  
    }
```

Also same issue with evaluateJavaScript as well. I am not getting any callback when loading "about:blank" using evaluateJavaScript. Seems same frames related issue.

Any leads would be appriciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If that are your iframes you should talk to them via javascript, there is no way to get regular delegate calls about them

Comment: Hi @Lu_ I am doing that via javascript only, but getting any response back to native code from native code. My webview has 2 frames running.

Comment: Weirdly, the `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)` delegate does work perfectly for the content in the iframe, but none of the delegate methods after this seem to fire.

Comment: Based on my comment above, I landed on a workaround that *kind of* works - by adding the impl for `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void)` and checking whether `navigationResponse.isForMainFrame`, I can at least know when the server has responded for the iFrame and make choices based on that.